# Pagination in java

Tags: java, pagination

I'm stuck for few days now, trying to develop a method managing pages of results in a search engine (just like google pagination system).

I have the total number of results, the current page (starts from 1...to...Last page), and the number of results per page (let's say 10 per page).

at the bottom of the JSP results page, I want to display the tabular data of pages as follows:

suppose the search engine returned 470 results.
- Based on "10 results per page", we'll have a total of 47 pages (470 / 10)

This is what I want to display

"previous   2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 Next" > when we click on the 10th page this is what should happen:

"previous   5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 Next" if the 14th page is clicked, then :

"previous   9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 Next" ans so on...

I have managed to do the following

```
public class Test {

public static int [] getIntervalNumberPages(
        final int pNumberHits,
        final int pNumberTotalHits,
        final int pNumberCurrentPage,
        final int pNumberResultsPerPage) {

    // Page interval
    final int NB_PAGES_INTERVAL = 10;

    // Initialise table
    int [] vResult = new int [0];

    // If no results found or if number of documents per page = 0
    if (pNumberHits != 0 && pNumberResultsPerPage != 0) {
        // Total number of pages
        int vNumberTotalPages = (int) java.lang.Math.ceil(pNumberTotalHits / (double) pNumberResultsPerPage);
        // First number of the list
        int vPremierNumero = 0;

        // Last number of the list
        int vDernierNumero = 0;
        // managing multiples
        if (pNumberCurrentPage >= NB_PAGES_INTERVAL && pNumberCurrentPage % NB_PAGES_INTERVAL == 0) {
            vPremierNumero = (pNumberCurrentPage / NB_PAGES_INTERVAL - 1) * NB_PAGES_INTERVAL + 1;
            vDernierNumero = java.lang.Math.min(vNumberTotalPages, (pNumberCurrentPage / NB_PAGES_INTERVAL - 1) * NB_PAGES_INTERVAL + NB_PAGES_INTERVAL);
        } else {
            vPremierNumero = pNumberCurrentPage / NB_PAGES_INTERVAL * NB_PAGES_INTERVAL + 1;
            vDernierNumero = java.lang.Math.min(vNumberTotalPages, pNumberCurrentPage / NB_PAGES_INTERVAL * NB_PAGES_INTERVAL + NB_PAGES_INTERVAL);
        }
        vResult = new int [vDernierNumero - vPremierNumero + 1];
        // Fill in table
        for (int vCpt = 0; vCpt < vResult.length; vCpt++) {
            vResult [vCpt] = vPremierNumero + vCpt;
        }
    }

return vResult;
}
}
```

However my code works like this:

"1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 Next" if I click on page 10 >
"Previous 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 Next" ans so on

can someone help me with is please??

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is just simple math.  The way you are renumbering does not match your described requirements.

```
 vPremierNumero = (pNumberCurrentPage / NB_PAGES_INTERVAL - 1) * NB_PAGES_INTERVAL
```

So let's plug in some numbers

```
 pNumberCurrentPage = 10
 NB_PAGES_INTERVAL = 10

 vPremierNumero = 10/9 * 10 = 100/9 = 11
```

So that's why you're first page is 11.  You want to shift this by NB_PAGES_INTERVAL/2 so that the number you clicked on is in the middle of the range.

Answer (score 2):

Your math is off. You probably want something like

> vPremierNumero = Math.max(1, pNumberCurrentPage - (NB_PAGES_INTERVAL /
>   2)); vDernierNumero = Math.min(vPremierNumero + NB_PAGES_INTERVAL,
>   vNumberTotalPages);

Comment: Thanks you very much.  This, in a very simple way solved the problem.  Thanks again for your precious help.

Comment: @user1353307: You don't say `thanks` literally here, but upvote helpful, right and good answers (upward triangle). The one which helped you the most or the finest answer you accept (check-sign).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic math for what you are trying to do, you can just plug in the rest

```
public static int[] getPagination(
        int currentPage,
        int maxPerPage,
        int totalResults) throws IOException {
    final int PAGES_BEFORE_AFTER = 5;
    final int MAX_PER_PAGE = 20;
    if (maxPerPage <= 0) {
        maxPerPage = MAX_PER_PAGE;
    }

    int startRecords = 0;
    int endRecords = totalResults;

    boolean has_pagination = (totalResults > maxPerPage);

    if (has_pagination) {
        int pageCount = totalResults / maxPerPage;
        if ((pageCount * maxPerPage) < totalResults) {
            pageCount++;
        }

        startRecords = (currentPage * maxPerPage) - maxPerPage;
        endRecords = (startRecords + maxPerPage);

        if (totalResults <= maxPerPage) {
            startRecords = 0;
            endRecords = totalResults;
        } else if (endRecords > totalResults) {
            endRecords = totalResults;
        }

        boolean prev_enabled = ((currentPage != 0) && (currentPage != 1));
        boolean next_enabled = ((pageCount != 0) && (pageCount != currentPage));

        int startIndex = 0;
        int stopIndex = pageCount;

        if (currentPage <= PAGES_BEFORE_AFTER) {
            startIndex = 0;
        } else {
            startIndex = (currentPage - PAGES_BEFORE_AFTER) - 1;
        }

        if ((currentPage + PAGES_BEFORE_AFTER) < pageCount) {
            stopIndex = currentPage + PAGES_BEFORE_AFTER;
        } else {
            stopIndex = pageCount;
        }

        for (int x = startIndex; x < stopIndex; x++) {
            boolean disabled = (currentPage == (x + 1));

            // buttons
        }
    }

    return new int[] { startRecords, endRecords };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation of the first and last number wasn't correct, try the following:

```
    // If no results found or if number of documents per page = 0
    if (pNumberHits != 0 && pNumberResultsPerPage != 0) {
        // Total number of pages
        // You shouldn't create an intermediate floating number here, this trick causes the same effect
        int vNumberTotalPages = (pNumberTotalHits + pNumberResultsPerPage - 1) / pNumberResultsPerPage;

        int firstIndex = pNumberCurrentPage - (NB_PAGES_INTERVAL / 2);
        int lastIndex = firstIndex + NB_PAGES_INTERVAL - 1;

        // First number of the list
        int vPremierNumero = Math.max(firstIndex, 1);

        // Last number of the list
        int vDernierNumero = Math.min(lastIndex, vNumberTotalPages);

        vResult = new int [vDernierNumero - vPremierNumero + 1];
        // Fill in table
        for (int vCpt = 0; vCpt < vResult.length; vCpt++) {
            vResult [vCpt] = vPremierNumero + vCpt;
        }
    }
```